# Repeated transient-socket connections - memory leak risk?

Tags: python, sockets, memory-leaks

I'm writing a script that opens a text file and loops through each line (pausing a few seconds between each one).  For each line, it opens a transient client socket connection and sends the text to a host server.  A host response may or may not come; it doesn't matter either way.

I've already bumped into the Python socket limitation where you can't reconnect with an existing socket object (because doing so triggers the exception `EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor'`).  So I'm creating a new socket instance for each transient connection.  The trick then of course becomes how to avoid a memory leak.

The way I've approached this is to push the whole portion of creating, using, and closing the socket to a function -- relying on Python's garbage collection to remove each instance after I'm done with it:

```
    import socket,select,time

    def transientConnect(host,port,sendData):
        response = ''
        sendSocket = socket.socket()
        sendSocket.connect((serverHost,serverPort))
        sendSocket.send(line)
        gotData = select.select([sendSocket],[],[],2)
        if (gotData[0]):response = sendSocket.recv(65535)
        sendSocket.close()
        return response

    scriptLines = open('testScript.txt','r').readlines()
    serverHost  = '127.0.0.1'
    serverPort  = 15004
    for line in scriptLines:
        response = transientConnect(serverHost,serverPort,line)
        print(response)
        time.sleep(3.0)
```

My questions:  (1) Will this approach work to avert any memory leaks?  (2) Is there a more direct way to make sure each instance is eliminated after I'm finished with it?

Comment: It is probably better to use `sendall` instead of `send`. The latter does not necessaryly send everything.

Comment: I think I'm missing something. Can't you just open one socket and send everything?

Comment: `.readlines()` is unnecessary (especially if you worry about memory). A file object is an iterator over lines by itself in Python. Also `.recv()` may return only partial response, to get full response put `select()` in a loop until `.recv()` returns empty string i.e., the other end closed connection.

Comment: @katrielalex, I'm using this script to simulate a handheld computer.  The app that the handheld would be running, works by brief, state-dependent, back-and-forth messages with an enterprise application on a server host.  The script allows me to 'play back' a complete suite of recorded activity from the handheld, and use that to validate the server's handling of the messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, it is normal to only use a socket for a single exchange. See the [socket HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sockets.html).

One of the nice things about python is that in general you don't have to worry about garbage collection. And you shouldn't unless you have real memory use problems.

From [this webpage](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/06/12/safely-using-destructors-in-python/), keep in mind that:

> "Python won’t clean up an object when it goes out of scope. It will clean it up when the last reference to it has gone out of scope."

So if the socket created inside the function isn't referenced elsewhere, it should go out of scope and be deallocated (but not gc-ed). What follows is probably specific to cpython. Read the documentation of [`gc.set_threshold()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.set_threshold) for an idea how garbage collection works in cpython. Especially:

> "When the number of allocations minus the number of deallocations exceeds *threshold0*, collection starts."

The standard values for the thresholds (in cpython) are:

```
In [2]: gc.get_threshold()
Out[2]: (700, 10, 10)
```

So there would heva to be a fair number of allocations before you get a gc run. You can *force* garbage collection by running [`gc.collect()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/gc.html#gc.collect).

Comment: Thanks.  Based on this it sounds like using the function will avert any memory leaks.  Plus, I understand a little more now about deallocation vs. gc.